# how to print RTC use Assembly interrupt vector 1ah

Tags: assembly, interrupt

I need to output an Interrupt 1h. (RTC).
But I don't know how to print RTC in console. Should I use interrupt 10h, or is there another way?
I already tried to find some in google, and I applied the interrupt 10 directly as below.

```
mov ah 0x02
int 0x1a
```

But it's not working. I know that the code is poor.
Please give me some help. If you can make example for me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: If I understand your question, it boils down to you wanting to print numbers?  It's unclear if you want to use the DOS services for output (which can be redirected) or if you are not running under DOS. Which one is the case?

Comment: i testing in ubuntu, and use bochs. It was a problem that happened during the making bootloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [docs](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0113.HTM) for `int 0x10`, we see a number of functions.  You didn't specify which you tried to use, but let's look at [ah=0x0e](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0129.HTM):

```
Expects: AH    0eH
         AL    character to write
         BL    (graphics modes only) foreground color number
```

The 'character to write' is the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of the character we want to display.  So for example if you want to write the character '7', you would put the ascii value for it (55 aka 0x37) into `al`.  Just putting 0x7 into `al` would be the ascii character for BEL (and would make the speaker beep).

So, what if you want to print the number 1234?  Well, you would need to call this function 4 times, with each of 49, 50, 51, 52.

I know, you're wondering if there is some way to output a string?  Sure.  For example there is [INT 0x10, ax=0x1300](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0132.HTM).  However, you STILL need to turn 1234 into the appropriate ascii characters, then call the BIOS function to output the string you have created.

Isn't there some sort of `printf("%d")` that does that conversion for me?  Not in the BIOS.  BIOS functions are designed to be very low level.  That's (part of) WHY there are operating systems, C runtime libraries, etc, so that people don't have to write all this junk.

If you don't want to write such a function yourself, there are asm 'libraries' out there that have collections of routines for performing this type of thing.

Comment: thank for your answer, but i already know how to use interrupt 0x10 that you explained. I want to know how to output RTC. (int 1A).
um... Should I convert the RTC to a string and print it out?

Comment: a) Int 10 prints ascii characters and ascii strings. b) RTC does not return ascii characters or ascii strings.  c) If the goal is to print the value returned from the RTC using int 10, you need to convert.

Comment: I do not know about that, but what exactly is interrupt 1ah returning?
i found this page : 'https://sites.google.com/site/liangweiqiang/Home/e5006/e5006classnote/jumptiming/int1ahclockservice' , in that page, maybe return BCD type. is right? and if that is ture, how to make BCD to Ascii?

Comment: There's a good description of what int 1ah returns [here](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_029.3.html). In short: 9:04:12 am will be reported as CH = 9, CL = 4, DH = 12. So, if you want to display CH (9), you must convert it to ascii '9' (57). If you were only dealing with numbers < 10, you could simply add 48.  But if seconds is 12, 12 + 48 is `<`.  Oops.  So you would need to do math (DH / 10) + 48 to get the '1' in the 12 seconds, (CL / 10) + 48 to get the '0' in 04 minutes, etc.  Or you might want to use each of these values as an index into a lookup table of strings.

Comment: Sorry sir but can you show using 'int 1ah' example for me?
I can't find use example : <

Comment: @DavidWohlferd that `DH` will be `0x12`, BCD way, not `0x0C`.